# Как записать в файл структуру с указателями?

Tags: c++, файлы, указатели, структуры-данных

Есть структура

```
struct  Data
{
    int iQuantLayer;            
    int* piQuantNInLayer;       
    double***pppdWeights;       
    double *pdIn;               
    double *pdOut;      
    double *pdBuff;             
};
```

Как записать её в файл таким образом, чтобы записались не адреса, а значения? С учетом того, что все указатели указывают на массивы.

Comment: Ну пишите допустим 4 байта - длина массива, потом сам массив...

Comment: Проблема в разыменовании указателя, индексации массива через [] или что?

Comment: Надо понимать, как именно сформированы массивы, а еще - в бинарный или текстовый файл вы хотите писать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться дедовским методом:

```
#include <stdio.h> // для FILE
#include <string>

struct  Data {
    std::string str;
    double *val;
};

int main() {
    Data *primary = new Data;
    primary->str = "TEST";
    primary->val = new double(99.99);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("buf.txt", "w");
    fwrite(primary, sizeof(Data), 1, fp); // запись.
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // смещение в конец.
    fwrite(primary->val, sizeof(*primary->val), 1, fp); // запись содержимого указателя.
    fclose(fp);

    Data *secondary = new Data;
    fp = fopen("buf.txt", "r");
    fread(secondary, sizeof(Data), 1, fp); // чтение.
    secondary->val = new double; // выделяем новую память.
    fseek(fp, sizeof(Data), SEEK_SET); // смещение к началу содержимого указателя.
    fread(secondary->val, sizeof(*secondary->val), 1, fp); // чтение содержимого указателя.
    fclose(fp);

    // Проверка:
    if (std::strcmp(primary->str.c_str(), secondary->str.c_str()) == 0
        && *primary->val == *secondary->val)
    {
        // Ура! Все сошлось.
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Извините, что упростил структуру. Но суть кода в следующем: записываем в файл содержимое структуры в бинарном виде; переходим в конец файла и записываем значение разыменовонного указателя; повторяем смещение и запись для всех указателей. Далее обратный процесс: читаем с начала файла структуру (указатели могут ссылаться уже на освобожденную память); выделяем новую память для указателей; смещаемся от начала файла на размер структуры; читаем объем по типу указателя; повторяем для всех указателей.

Answer (score 1):

1. Учитывая, что Вы используете массивы в C-стиле, то Вы должны где-то хранить кол-во элементов этого массива. На основании Вашего кода непонятно, где хранится это значение(-я). Потом это `double***pppdWeights;` - где инициализируется, как  и т.п. Выкладывайте, пожалуйста, больше кода, иначе проблема может быть неясна.
2. Далее, Вы пишете *чтобы записались не адреса а значения*.

   ```
   int * p = new int(10);
   std::cout << p << std::endl; // выводится адрес
   std::cout << *p << std::endl; // выводится значение
   ```

   Это был пример для указателя на `int`. Для массива будет как-то так:

   ```
   const std::size_t size = 10;
   int * array = new int [size];
   // ... - заполняем массив
   for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
       std::cout << array[i] << std::endl;
   ```
3. Для вывода в файл вместо стандартного потока `cout` используете `ofstream` и выводите... Надеюсь, Вы знаете, как работать со стандартными потоками вывода.

Answer (score 0):

У меня такое решение получилось

Использовал winapi

```
class LoaderNetw : public DataCl
    {
    public:
        LoaderNetw(Data *);
        ~LoaderNetw();
        int openNetw();
        void write();
        void read();
    private:
        void *file;
        unsigned char type = 0;
        unsigned char ch;
    };

int neural_network_lib::LoaderNetw::openNetw()
{
    std::exception e = std::exception("File it's open", 0);
    try
    {
        this->file = ::CreateFile(TEXT(url),
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,
            NULL,
            OPEN_ALWAYS,
            FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
            NULL);
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED)
            throw std::exception::exception("File not open", 1);
    }
    catch (const std::exception&e)
    {
        return 1;
    }


    return 0;
}

void neural_network_lib::LoaderNetw::write()    {
    ::SetFilePointer(this->file, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
    DWORD fl = 0;
    ::WriteFile(this->file,
        &this->type, sizeof this->type, &fl, NULL);
    ::SetFilePointer(this->file, fl, 0, FILE_CURRENT);
    ::WriteFile(this->file, 
        &this->d->iQuantLayer, 
        sizeof this->d->iQuantLayer, 
        &fl, 
        NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < this->d->iQuantLayer; i++) {
        ::SetFilePointer(this->file, fl, 0, FILE_CURRENT);
        ::WriteFile(this->file,
            &this->d->piQuantNInLayer[i],
            sizeof i,
            &fl,
            NULL);
    }
        for (int i = 1; i < this->d->iQuantLayer; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < this->d->piQuantNInLayer[i]; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < this->d->piQuantNInLayer[i - 1]; k++) {
                    ::SetFilePointer(this->file, fl, 0, FILE_CURRENT);
                    ::WriteFile(this->file,
                        &this->d->pppdWeights[i][j][k],
                        sizeof this->d->pppdWeights[i][j][k],
                        &fl,
                        NULL);
                }


}

void neural_network_lib::LoaderNetw::read() {
    DWORD fl = 0;
    ::SetFilePointer(this->file, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
    ::ReadFile(this->file, &this->ch, sizeof this->ch, &fl, NULL);
    ::SetFilePointer(this->file, fl, 0, FILE_CURRENT);
    ::ReadFile(this->file,
        &this->d->iQuantLayer,
        sizeof this->d->iQuantLayer,
        &fl,
        NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < this->d->iQuantLayer; i++) {
        ::SetFilePointer(this->file, fl, 0, FILE_CURRENT);
        ::ReadFile(this->file, &this->d->piQuantNInLayer[i], sizeof double(1), &fl, NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < this->d->iQuantLayer; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < this->d->piQuantNInLayer[i]; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < this->d->piQuantNInLayer[i - 1]; k++) {
                ::SetFilePointer(this->file, fl, 0, FILE_CURRENT);
                ::ReadFile(this->file,
                    &this->d->pppdWeights[i][j][k],
                    sizeof double(1),
                    &fl,
                    NULL);
            }

}
```